# vb.net string to chartjs data field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vb.net, chart.js

I am using the latest ChartJS, as of the time of this writing, and I am having a problem with getting the data values read by chartjs. I am using asp.net vb.net as the backend. I am currently loading a hidden html element with a string value "['label1','label2','label3']" and reading that element into var lbls

```
<script>

    var ctxL = document.getElementById("lineChart"); 
    var lbls = document.getElementById("hdhead").value;
    var cd = document.getElementById("cdata").value;

    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctxL);
    var ctxLdata = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: eval("[" + lbls + "]"),
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "2018",
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: eval("[" + cd + "]")
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    };

</script>
```

When passing the string to the hidden element I've tried these

```
"{'label1'},{'label2'},{'label3'}"
"[{'label1'},{'label2'},{'label3'}]"
""label1","label2","label3""
```

I don't know a lot about javascript and have been searching here and the internet to find a way to get the data in the correct format so the chart will read it correctly.

When I load the page the chart doesn't show up but I can see that the data variables are loaded but in string format and not data format. What is the best approach to convert the string into usable data for the chart?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VB.Net to output the data values in a JSON file, 
Then using javascript, you can read the generated JSON file as input for the ChartJS plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I will research this.

Comment: After researching the JSON approach and failing at my attempts to use it correctly it has come to my conclusion that vb.net is not the best backend to use. What recommendations would you all suggest to use? I will need to pull data from a sql server and display in a chart among other elements. I do know that client scripting for this is a no no for many reasons. My failed attempts with the JSON come down to lack of documentation for creating the JSON file in vb.net but there is plenty of documentation on parsing JSON file's in vb.net.

Comment: why not PHP? or JavaScript?